# private and public ipaddress on azure cloud

Tags: azure, centos, g-wan

I'm trying to run gwan on an Azure cloud machine. But I get issues with network interfaces, or I simply cannot hit the machine with the browser.

I believe the issue has to do with internal IP address assigned by the Azure router, but also I could be missing some critical security issue (or something else)

The machine is running CentOS.

Here is my configuration:

1. /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config

   added a rule for accepting traffic via port 80

   > -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
2. /etc/hosts

   added the public IP address and mapped that to a subdomain of cloudapp.net

   > 192.12.45.23  myappname.cloudapp.net
3. gwan_linux64-bit

   changed the directories to suit the public IP.

   > mv 0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0 
   >   192.12.45.23_80/#192.12.45.23
4. run gwan

   > sudo ./gwan
   >
   > can't listen on 168.62.8.160:80 (Cannot assign requested address)
   >   Available network interfaces (2):
   >   127.0.0.1 12.109.24.35
5. Then I tried both 12.109.24.35 and 127.0.0.1 interfaces - 
   gwan ran without an error,  but I couldn't browse the machine using the public IP of 168.62.8.160:80

further info:
/etc/sysconfig/network  doesnt use the FQDN myappname.cloudapp.net but

```
HOSTNAME=myappname
NETWORKING=yes
```

as well, /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DHCP_HOSTNAME=myappname

DEVICE=eth0
```

Comment: Did you create an Input Endpoint on port 80? You can check this via the portal, when looking at the configuration for the virtual machine.

Comment: thanks. i did. still doesnt connect. strangely the machine is both a VM and a 'Cloud service'. Why both categories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Azure and its specificities. But it seems that you are missing a *system* configuration for your IP address (a problem that has little to do with G-WAN).

Your error is:

```
"can't listen on 168.62.8.160:80
Available network interfaces (2): 127.0.0.1 12.109.24.35"
```

On a Linux machine you would have to assign the `168.62.8.160` IP address to one of your network adapters in order for the system to be able to use it.

For temporary changes: `ifconfig eth0:1 168.62.8.160`

For permanent changes:

```
vim /etc/network/interfaces
--------------------------------------------------------------
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 12.109.24.35
   network ...            // replace ... by the relevant data
   netmask ...            // replace ... by the relevant data

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
   address 168.62.8.160
   network ...            // replace ... by the relevant data
   netmask ...            // replace ... by the relevant data
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

...and then run: `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

That's what would work if you were running Linux, just in case that may help to understand what you are missing on Microsoft Azure.

Comment: it is system config issue. i thought maybe i could get around it by binding to the current interface but run under the ip address. like so: gwan_linux64-bit/12.109.23.35_80/#168.62.8.160... or more generally. gwan/localip_port/publicip